# Unwanted bump on a mesh after Boolean and Subdivision Surface

Tags: modifiers, topology, subdivision-surface, bump

I did a hole in my mesh in Blender 2.82 with boolean modifier, and I made some changes about topology so that the subdivision surface modifier can work properly. I removed all the doubles, and I checked the normals, they are fine.

[image: image 1]

But the result isn't what I've expected. We can see a bump, right below the hole (in red on the image).

[image: image 2]

Does someone have any idea ? I don't have any problem when I do the same thing on a sphere. Thank You !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the kind of topology you need. It has ring-based loops of quads going around the hole.

[image]

It produces a rim with no bumps when you add your Subdivision Surface modifier.

[image]

Comment: It works ! Thank you very much for taking the time to help me.